# How do I return specific parts of a string of characters from every row?

Tags: string, unix, awk, grep

I have a file (gencode.vM23.transcripts.fa) that contains many rows that has multiple identifiers for a gene as well as the sequence. Each row starts with > to represent a new gene

I want make a new file that just contains the first piece of info >ENSMUST00000193812.1 as well as all of the DNA sequence sequence. And then do this for all of the rows that start with '>' I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. Any help is much appreciated

```
>ENSMUST00000193812.1|ENSMUSG00000102693.1|OTTMUSG00000049935.1|OTTMUST00000127109.1|4933401J01Rik-201|4933401J01Rik|1070|TEC|
AAGGAAAGAGGATAACACTTGAAATGTAAATAAAGAAAATACCTAATAAAAATAAATAAA
AACATGCTTTCAAAGGAAATAAAAAGTTGGATTCAAAAATTTAACTTTTGCTCATTTGGT
ATAATCAAGGAAAAGACCTTTGCATATAAAATATATTTTGAATAAAATTCAGTGGAAGAA
TGGAATAGAAATATAAGTTTAATGCTAAGTATAAGTACCAGTAAAAGAATAATAAAAAGA
AATATAAGTTGGGTATACAGTTATTTGCCAGCACAAAGCCTTGGGTATGGTTCTTAGCAC
TAAGGAACCAGCCAAATCACCAACAAACAGAGGCATAAGGTTTTAGTGTTTACTATTTGT
ACTTTTGTGGATCATCTTGCCAGCCTGTAGTGCAACCATCTCTAATCCACCACCATGAAG
GGAACTGTGATAATTCACTGGGCTTTTTCTGTGCAAGATGAAAAAAAGCCAGGTGAGGCT
GATTTATGAGTAAGGGATGTGCATTCCTAACTCAAAAATCTGAAATTTGAAATGCCGCCC
```

Comment: You say each row starts with a `>`, and I assume that "row" means "line". Is that correct? And, if so, is there any need to filter out "lines not starting with `>`"?

Comment: Which part of a line is the "first piece"? Is there a specific delimiter character which tells you that a piece is done? When you are on a line that starts with a `>` is there only one chunk of text on that line you want to extract? What I mean is that it *looks* as if  you have multiple pipe-delimited identifiers in your sample. Di you want all of them for each line, or just the first one?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you data file contains the `' '` (spaces) shown in your question and whether the number of fields separated by `'|'` is constant for each line. Given some of your fields have a space after `'|'` and others don't, it looks like the spaces are a result of pasting the long line into your question.

**If The Number of Fields is Constant for Every Line**

If you have the same number of fields and separators (`'|'`) in each line, an `awk` solution is trivial if the 1st field is always the one beginning with `"ENSMUST..."` (or with `">ENSMUST..."` if the `'>'` is included in the file) and the 9th field is your gene sequence, then you can do:

```
awk -F '|' '{print $1 "|" $9}' infile > newoutfile
```

**If Line Format Not Constant**

If the line format isn't constant as far as the number of fields, or field where the one beginning with `"ENSMUST..."` and your gene sequence occur, you will need to test for  the presence of each and output the field they are found in. The one assumption made is that the field with `"ENSMUST..."` occurs before the field with your gene sequence in the line. To handle this condition, you could do:

```
awk -F '|' ' {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^>ENSMUST/)    # remove the '>' if not actually in file
            printf "%s|", $1
        else if (match($i,/[^ACGT]/)==0) {
            print $i
            break
        }
}' infile > newoutfile
```

Above you simply loop over each field until the one beginning with `"ENSMUST..."` is found (it is output followed by the separator `'|'`), and then continue looping until a field made up of only the characters `[ACGT]` is found (as used above, you check and discard any field that has something other than `ACGT` within it and exit the loop once the gene sequence is found and output.

**Example Use/Output**

In either case above, your `newoutfile` would contain the fields:

```
ENSMUST00000193812.1|AAGGAAAGAGGATAACACTTGAAA.....
```

or if the `'>'` is in the file:

```
>ENSMUST00000193812.1|AAGGAAAGAGGATAACACTTGAAA.....
```

Look thing over and let me know if this is what you intended and whether you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thank you sir! A bit of ambiguity to deal with, but should be reasonably covered.

Answer (score 0):

Without a more complete set of sample data (or answers to some of my questions) it's hard to be sure, but probably something like

```
grep ^'>' gencode.vM23.transcripts.fa | cut -d '|' -f1 > subset
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to delete all substrings starting with `|`, use

```
cut -d'|' -f1 gencode.vM23.transcripts.fa
```